# Does WSProxy have an Upsert Batch?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, wsproxy

I'm looking at using WSProxy in my ssjs script to upsert multiple rows into a Data Extension.

I know there's updateBatch for updating records and createBatch for inserting new records. However, I'm trying to run an upsert because there may be new records in my batch.

Also, I've tried using the updateBatch method with saveOptions

```
var options = {SaveOptions: [{'PropertyName': '*', SaveAction: 'UpdateAdd'}]};
var res = api.updateBatch('DataExtensionObject', updateArr, options);
```

However, it gave an error stating that 0 out of the expect 1 records were updated.
When trying it with the createBatch method, it would give an error stating that the primary keys were already taken by an existing record.

Comment: It might be something elsewhere in your code causing issues, or a data mismatch because that is the correct syntax for batch upserting. (https://www.ssjsdocs.xyz/shared/batches/update.html)

Comment: I followed the guide linked but it was for updating. It worked when I didn't have new records but when I tried adding new records, it gave me an error.